# UK Short Term Student Visa

Tags: united-kingdom, indian-citizens, study

I'm from India and I am a mature student. I am 25 and currently I am enrolled in an open university here. I have been accepted at Birkbeck University for Theater and English BA program.

Since I have been out of full time education, I was advised to take up a short foundation course before I take up full time education especially since my subject is English and Theater.

I applied for the ELAS program at SOAS and have received an offer. So now I am applying for short term student visa. I am unemployed and I do not earn so my parents will be funding my studies.

These are the documents I am enclosing

1. visa application
2. photograph
3. SOAS offer letter, SOAS deposit payment letter and student visa letter
4. Birkbeck Offer Letter
5. Pearson Test Certificate
6. 12th standard certificate
7. TB test certificate
8. Bank statement Letters from my fathers fixed deposit and savings account. My mother has also enclosed her savings account statement and bank statement
9. My fathers salary statement
10. Affidavit of Support from my parents
11. Open University Student ID card
12. Short online courses certificates
13. passport
14. accommodation application print out (the accommodation isn't sure when I will receive an offer so they advised me to include the application status print out in case the confirmation status does not reach me before document submission day)

Are these documents sufficient or do I need to include more? Also, last year I had applied for a visitor visa to U.K but was refused because I had not provided an invitation letter by my aunt who lives in Birmingham.

I have included my plans in the  application that I will return to India to apply for a Tier 4 visa for Birkbeck course.

Answer (score 1):

You're always better off providing more documentation than specified, if you feel there's any chance of it helping.

You're also probably going to want to include a letter documenting the refusal last year, the reason, and why this is not a problem for your student visa.

Your ultimate goal with the documents provided is to allay any fears and answer any questions they have about your application. So at a minimum, include ALL the documents they request, and then if you think there's any possible questions (eg about your previous refusal), add letters or documents to support / explain this.